# How can i modify a sql connection string at runtime?

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I query a database as follows:

```
string connString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User 
     id=UserName;Password=Secret;";    
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Orders", connString);
conn.Open();
```

The issue is that the server may require the settings TrustServerCertificate and Encrypt

So if i run the above it will fail with error

```
  SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
  (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)]
```

but if i have the connString as

```
"Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User 
 id=UserName;Password=Secret;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true");
```

then it will connect without a problem and the select will run.

So I may need to change the connection string on the fly
Is there a smart way I can make a modification to the above code to check that if the error is returned I then retry the select with the new , modified connection string ?

Comment: So you dont know in advance if the server you are connecting to require TrustServerCertificate or not?

Comment: that ight i dont know , but if i get an exception error as above i need to readjust the connection string and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enhancing the solution provided by @ɐsɹǝʌ ǝɔıʌ:

```
    string connectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Userid=UserName;Password=Secret;";
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            command.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Userid=UserName;Password=Secret;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true";
            connection.Open();
           
        }
        finally
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can i make this into a method ?

Comment: Yes. You can definitely do that.

Answer (score 2):

Place your code into a [try](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) block and catch the [SqlException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Then, change your connection string and retry the connection.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Userid=UserName;Password=Secret;";
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
           }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        command.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Userid=UserName;Password=Secret;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true";
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write($"Error: {ex.Message}")
    }
 }
```

Comment: How does that actually re-run the select cmd , it just changes the connection string ?

Comment: would it be better to try and connect and if it gets a certificate exception change the strig an re-run , because when it is re-run with the modification , it will work ?

Comment: That is what it is doing.

Comment: ah yes sorry ,  you are right , thankyou

Comment: @Jennifer You're not running the command in your code as you are stuck when opening the connection. You'll need to send the command text to the connection and build a SqlDataReader once the connection is open. See edited answer.